# Is it possible to UPDATE before DELETE at once in MERGE statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like improve my SQL MERGE statement to UPDATE row before DELETE it.

I've table [Produkt] with [UsId] column with is sometimes NULL. I'd like to UPDATE [UsId] before DELETE because I've trigger for logging deleted rows and I need UsId to my trigger.

My SQL statement looks like:

```sql
MERGE Produkt Target
USING (SELECT 9558,
              'A000043179',
              1.0000) Source (TowId, NosnikId, Opakowanie)
ON ( Target.TowId = Source.TowId
 AND Target.NosnikId = Source.NosnikId
 AND Target.Opakowanie = Source.Opakowanie)
WHEN MATCHED AND Target.Ilosc - 15 * 8.0000 = 0 THEN DELETE
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET Target.Ilosc = Target.Ilosc - 15 * 8.0000,
                             Target.UsId = 2;
```

I know that I can send UPDATE statement before MERGE but I'm curious if it's possible to do it in one MERGE statement, for example:

```sql
MERGE Produkt AS Target
USING (SELECT 9558, 'A000043179', 1.0000) AS Source (TowId, NosnikId, Opakowanie) ON (Target.TowId = Source.TowId AND Target.NosnikId = Source.NosnikId AND Target.Opakowanie = Source.Opakowanie)
WHEN MATCHED AND Target.Ilosc - 15 * 8.0000 = 0
THEN /* UPDATE SET Target.UsId = 2 AND/THEN */ DELETE
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET Target.Ilosc = Target.Ilosc - 15 * 8.0000, Target.UsId = 2;
```

Comment: Whitespace and Linebreaks are paramount to making readable text; not just in code. Please get into the habit of making good use of both. Poor/bad formatting is not going to help you or others when you need to be able to quickly read and understand your code. Using indentation and line breaks really helps easily distinguish specific code blocks and sections, and make finding errors far easier when a line only contains 10's of characters, rather than 100's.

Comment: I've used a tool to format your first query for you, but as your second query isn't valid (has syntax errors) you'll need to do that one yourself. Please take the time do do so, as the query is impossible to read as it stands.

Comment: Might it not be better to fix the triggered code to handle UsId being null?

Comment: Considering the "problems" with `MERGE` ([So, you want to use MERGE, eh?](//sqlblog.org/merge)) and you want to control the order in which the DML operations are done, why not use explicit `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements instead? You avoid the caveats of using a `MERGE` (you're not even using a `HOLDLOCK` here) and it solves the problem.

Comment: If you want a specific order use separate statements. You don't gain a lot (if anything) from MERGE. The overall operation isn't atomic so you do need explicit transactions. Only the separate DELETE or UPDATE operations are.  There's no order guarantee, and one of the problems is that MERGE could end up processing the same row multiple times. The very fact you need the operations to happen in a certain order means you *do* need two separate statements

Comment: [Documentation MERGE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16): _The MERGE statement can't update the same row more than once, or update and delete the same row._

Comment: How about you show us the trigger code, I'm sure it can be improved instead.

Comment: Or better still, open a new question about the trigger - since its fundamentally changing it if you edut it

Comment: My rule of thumb is, if you have to ask question here about merge or pivot, you shouldn't use any of these :D Do the ol' boring double statement and feel the wind blowing on you from behind